# How to refresh listview builder after using delete method from api using Bloc in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How do I refresh the listview builder after using the delete method from the API using Bloc in Flutter? After the delete method is completed, I want that data to disappear from the list, but it won't. I have to refresh the page for it to disappear. In Bloc Listener, there is a state called success. How do I implement code in this state so that it will disappear when it is successful?

```
    ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemCount: _data.length,
    itemBuilder: (_, index) {
    return BlocListener<DeleteExperienceCubit, DeleteExperienceState>(
    listener: (context, state) {
    state.when(
    initial: () => const Containers(),
    loading: () =>  const CircularProgressIndicator(),
    noInternet: () => null,
    error: (message) => null,
     success: (data, message) {context.showSnackbarSuccess (message: message);
                                                },
                                              );
                                            },
    child: BlocBuilder<DeleteExperienceCubit,DeleteExperienceState>(
     builder: (context, state) {return ExperienceContainer(
     companyName:  _data[index].company!.name!,
     from: _data[index].from!,
     deleteTap: () async {
     await context .read<DeleteExperienceCubit>().deleteRepository(
      id: _data[index].id!);
   );
   },
   ),
```

Answer (score 1):

We started wrong since you declare a `Listener` and then a `Builder` of the same Bloc. Use the Consumer.

Apart, leave the Listener only if you want to "listen" for changes like Snackbars, Navigate between screens, not to change your widgets.

```dart
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: _data.length,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
        return BlocConsumer<DeleteExperienceCubit, DeleteExperienceState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            state.when(
              success: (data, message) {
                context.showSnackbarSuccess(message: message);
              },
            );
          },
          builder: (context, state) {
            state.when(
              initial: () => Container(),
              loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
              noInternet: () => null,
              error: (message) => null,
              success: (data, message) {
                return ExperienceContainer(
                  companyName: _data[index].company!.name!,
                  from: _data[index].from!,
                  deleteTap: () async {
                    await context
                        .read<DeleteExperienceCubit>()
                        .deleteRepository(id: _data[index].id!);
                  },
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
```